# Sign up customization with separate email verification using SendGrid

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I am using Azure AD B2C with Custom Policies to implement a sign-up flow where user has to verify the email before proceeds to sign up page.

I found an example here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup/policy/SignUpOrSignIn_SplitEmailVerificationAndSignUp.xml#L61-L77 and I try to modify this code and add a DisplayControl and from there I implement the custom email verification flow.

The `emailVerificationControl` is also based on the other sample code found here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol/policy/SendGrid/DisplayControl_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L142-L163

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="isForgotPassword">
        <DisplayName>isForgotPassword</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Whether the user has clicked Forgot Password</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="termsOfUseConsentChoice">
        <DisplayName></DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Enumeration Text=" I agree to the Terms Of Service" Value="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentYes" SelectByDefault="false" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Email Verification</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
          <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentChoice" DefaultValue="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentNo" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <!-- Sample: Disable session management for sign-up page -->
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">
          <DisplayName>Forgot your password?</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <SubJourneys>
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
  </SubJourneys>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Everything seems working fine so far. I can enter my email address and it will send the code using via SendGrid, I can click verify code button and it successfully verified and has a continue button.

[1. The DisplayControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7gxV.png)

[2. Send code to email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LSnR.png)

[3. Verify email address and continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tme0d.png)

But after I click the continue button the page just crash and says, "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occured."

[4. Sign up page does not show up, it crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8MeA.png)

The only changes I made is the `DisplayControl` and it works fine without it (which in this case it uses the Microsoft's default email verification service) so I suppose there is something I did wrong...I would like to get some help if anyone has done anything similar with Azure AD B2C before.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure B2C ClaimsTransformation error with Display Control OutputClaim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251477/azure-b2c-claimstransformation-error-with-display-control-outputclaim)

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this github issue: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/193

If you are using the following samples [Split Email Verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and [Custom Email Verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

The only changes required from these sample policies is that you change the Output Claim from

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
  <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
   <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
   <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </InputClaims>
  <DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
<!----------- CHANGE THIS LINE ------------------------------->
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
  <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
   <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
   <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </InputClaims>
  <DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
<!----------- TO THIS LINE ------------------------------->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I also noticed this must be added to the following technical profiles: [EmailVerification, LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress]

```
<InputClaims>
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
</InputClaims>
```

The UserJourney should look like

- EmailVerification
- LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail
- AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId
- JwtIssuer

PS: It's also important to note that your ContentDefinitions must be version greater than 2.0.0.