# How in B2C sign-up Email Verification control “Verify Code” button to open Registration page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The sample “Separate the Email Verification and User Registration into 2 separate screens”
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup
has separate steps :
2.  Click “Verify code” that returns message “You can now continue” and then
3 click “Continue” to open Registration page.

Continue button is  redundant. How can I combine the steps and if “Verify code” is successful, redirect to next page?

Note that I am using   [emailVerificationControl](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol)
to connect to email provider
similar to [Azure B2C ClaimsTransformation error with Display Control OutputClaim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251477/azure-b2c-claimstransformation-error-with-display-control-outputclaim)

Update: I’ve implemented some hack as I described in [How to add JavaScript event handlers for action completion in B2C emailVerificationControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76515868/how-to-add-javascript-event-handlers-for-action-completion-in-b2c-emailverificat/76521926#76521926) , but I wish to hear about better, more out-of-box solution.